# Is there anyway to use cognitive services to detect if a string contains words vs just junk shift chars/gibberish?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to find a way to use cognitive services to detect if a string contains a piece of coherent text or is just junk. Example:

> SDF#%# ASFSDS b

vs

> Hi my name is Sam.

This seems impossible to do. I had the idea of running the text through the keywords text analysis (which would give me a keyword of ASDSDS (how useful!)) and then run that keyword though the Bing Spell Check. I'm not sure what is going on in the the USA but it seems ASFSDS is English. It really is quite... erm.. dumb.

I've tried running similar text through a bunch of services (like language detection) and they all seem convinced that my gibberish samples are 100% coherent English.

I'm going to quiz an MS rep about it on Friday but I was wondering if anyone has achieved something like this using Cognitive services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a binary *is-word-or-not* question, what you might consider instead is the probability of a word being gibberish.  You can then choose a threshold that you like.

For computing word probalities, you might try the Web Language Model [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/web-language-model/home).  You could look at the joint probability, as an example.  For your set of words, the response looks as follows (values for the `body` corpus):

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "words": "sdf#%#",
      "probability": -12.215
    },
    {
      "words": "asfsds",
      "probability": -12.215
    },
    {
      "words": "b",
      "probability": -3.127
    },
    {
      "words": "hi",
      "probability": -3.905
    },
    {
      "words": "my",
      "probability": -2.528
    },
    {
      "words": "name",
      "probability": -3.128
    },
    {
      "words": "is",
      "probability": -2.201
    },
    {
      "words": "sam.",
      "probability": -12.215
    },
    {
      "words": "sam",
      "probability": -4.431
    }
  ]
}
```

You will notice a couple of idiosyncrasies:

1. Probabilities are negative.  This is because they are logarithmic.
2. All terms are case-folded.  This means that the corpus won't
   distinguish between, say, GOAT and goat.
3. Caller must perform a
   certain amount of normalization themselves (note probability of
   `sam.` vs `sam`)
4. Corpora are only available for the en-us market.  This could be problematic 
   depending on your use case.

An advanced use case would be computing *conditional* probabilities, i.e. the probability of a word *in the context of words preceding it*.

Comment: Thanks cthrash. This is looking very promising. Do you have any tips on the best way to normalise the text? I suppose given that it is english only I could just strip out anything not [A-Za-z]. But that wont work very well (or at all) if/when they add support for more languages though.

Comment: I don't know if the tokenization of the WebLM is public.  You don't want to necessary strip all non-alphanumeric, especially if you want to flag `good#%&` as a non-word, for example.  You might keep it simple for now, say, dropping any punctuation followed by whitespace.